# magento total_due, grand_total_due

Tags: magento

Magento topic.

Who can explain what stores in grand_total_due or total_due column in sales_flat_order?

Some orders have these two columns equal to 0.01 and client is charged (total prices + 0.01) but in the checkout page client cant see this price (means 0.01)

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the 'due' amount is how much hasn't been paid.  It is updated after each paid invoice.  Invoices don't always have to be for the full amount of the order, although I only know a way of doing that from admin and not the customer checkout.  When another payment is made it includes the due amount so that the customer does not owe anything more.